# Creating Dynamic Data Frames in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Data Frame `DF1` with three columns `A`, `B` and `C` with values 3, 2 and 100.

What I am trying to do is loop through DF1 to create two new dataframes called `DF_A` and `DF_B`....dynamically (assign names dynamically) such that

```
DF_A = 3, 100, 300 # (i.e. A*100)
DF_B = 2, 100, 200 # (i.e. B* 100)
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there is no way to dynamically create DataFrames. In another Stackoverflow question, a method of storing it in a dictionary was recommended. It can be done with the following code.

```python
import pandas as pd

DF1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [3], "B": [2], "C": [100]})

DF_list = {}
for i in ["A", "B"]:
    DF = pd.DataFrame({})
    DF[i] = DF1[[i]]
    DF["C"] = DF1[["C"]]
    DF["value"] = DF[i] * DF["C"]
    DF_list["DF_" + i] = DF

print(DF_list)
# {'DF_A':    A    C  value
# 0  3  100    300, 'DF_B':    B    C  value
# 0  2  100    200}
```

Comment: @Keiku...thanks a lot for sharing this ....very helpful ....implemented it successfully....! Thanks -JK

Comment: @Keiku...I have a follow up question. So I added line DF ["Name"] =i within the loop since I wanted to have a column in a data frame which says A for DF_A and B for DF_B....the problem is that if I have more than 1 row in the data frame...i cannot run this code since it returns only the first row... does my question make sense......in sql language what I am ultimately trying to translate is select 'A' as [Name] , A,C, A*C into DF_A from  DF1

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by adding a line DF["Name"] = pd.DataFrame([i] *len(DF1),columns="Name"))